# Resistor without terminals?

Tags: resistors

I have two terminals which I will measure resistivity between. I will be manually touching the terminal pair to different value resistors.

The terminal pair might look something like a 9v battery plug:
[image]

I don't want to be precise about where I touch the resistor (lining up the terminals with the resistor wires).

Is there some kind of "pad resistor" (the size of a small coin) in which I can just touch two terminals anywhere on the surface and have the same effect as if i were using set resistors?

Note: the reason I am using resistors is so I can have a series of pads with unique signature based on resistance over the terminals. If there is some other solution in which I can have unique "pads" be recognised by a microcontroller as different without using resistors, this will work also.

Thanks!

Comment: it is difficult to visualize what you are talking about .... please post a picture

Comment: oops, i failed to realize that you are the OP that asked about the thumb contacts on your previous post

Comment: Haha you are uniquely positioned to answer then. Thanks again for the other post.

Comment: here is something similar ... http://maestroglove.com/

Comment: Ahh I’ve seen similar products. I’m not a fan of the whole glove design. I’m playing around with alternatives. Thanks though!

Comment: maybe a color sensor and different colored fingertips might work

Comment: Minor point. If you are measuring high value resistors using bare fingers you might get a false reading

Comment: Hi Dirk, could you elaborate on this. The idea is to have the "resistor" attached to a fingertip, and to simply place it over the two terminals as outlined above. How will the finger affect this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could have a pad of material with a certain resistivity, and make pads with different thicknesses of the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

different conductive materials have a different bulk resistivity. so you could use them in this. eg get thimbles mage from or coated with conductive rubber in 4 different formulations (or the same formulation in different thicknesses) but the readings you get will to some extent be pressure dependent.

a better solution is probably to instead make a pad with many terminals
that are all fed to a single resistor via a diode network, that way even if each of the contacts bridges multipler terminals you can still read the single resistor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMvWdl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Assuming four of these thimbles, do you think the formulations or thicknesses could be so that there is no overlap between their resistive value range, regardless of pressure variation?

Comment: probably not... see my second suggestion.

Comment: Interesting idea! As I mentioned I’m a bit inexperienced with circuits. Is there anything off the shelf that would match this criteria? And if not, do you think such a design could be implemented on a 10x10mm medium?

Comment: Also back to the first solution, could I use completely different materials? Rubber, wood, copper, etc. would these work and have resistive differences big enough to avoid overlap?

Comment: rubber and wood will look similar to air electrically, all metals will looks similar. so no. probably won't work.

Comment: Thanks Jasen. So I can essentially abandon the idea of having pads of different resistances? 
If so, the circuit design you provided, do you see that being made in a space of 10x10mm? And is there anything like this currently available?

Comment: Also with the diode network, if one terminal happens to span two of the diode contacts, will that have any adverse effect?

Comment: in 10mm size it could be made on a two sided circuit board with the contact pads on one side and the parts on the other, two terminal surface mount devices are fairlty to solder by hand, dual diodes are available which could be handy.  two diodes will have only a slightly lower resistance/voltage drop than 1 diode  (about 10% difference) if you  get thje bias current right it shouldn't be hard to pick which resistor it is.

Comment: Hi Jasen. I have this circuit working, but my resistor readings are quite inaccurate. I imagine this has to do with the voltage drop/current bias you mentioned. Could you recommend how i can adjust for this?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

Use RFID keyfobs ([example](https://www.jaycar.com.au/spare-13-56mhz-rfid-nfc-key-fob/p/ZZ8970)) and your reader is an RFID reader. You might be able to adjust the reader's signal strength so that it won't read the fob until the fob is actually touching the reader. (or just put something in front of it to weaken the signal)

If these are too big for you, you may be able to crack open the plastic, re-arrange the coil into a smaller coil, and mold them into your own plastic.

Each keyfob has a unique ID number which the reader can see.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

Find a material with a measurable resistance in-between "none" and "lots". (i.e. not a conductor, not an insulator either). A grid of pencil lines on paper *might* work for a prototype.

Make a pad of this material. Measure the resistance you get, with the terminals in different positions and with different amounts of pressure.

See if you can make several different pads, with different amounts of conductive material, so the resistances don't overlap. Maybe different pencils, or [different metal](https://www.bluesea.com/resources/108/Electrical_Conductivity_of_Materials) sheets (if you can measure low resistances), or different metal mesh, or something like graphite (in different thicknesses).

Comment: Great solution! I will try this and see how it compares to the solution I'm currently employing. You've been a great help