# Finding value of resistor between two diodes

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, resistors, diodes

I'm using an Arduino and I have the following circuit:

[image]

I couldn't find the symbol for analog signal, so the voltmeter represents a connection to the Arduino's analog input pin.

How can I work out R1? I have used voltage divider, but it doesn't take into account the voltage drop over the two diodes (which I believe is 500millivolts each).

Thanks!

Comment: can you increase the voltage at all?

Comment: What is the purpose of your circuit? We can't answer your question without this information.

Comment: In any way, the diodes have a forward voltage drop. Subtract this from 3.3V and you have the input voltage for the divider.

Comment: Are you able to disconnect the circuit from the arduino, and are you able to use a multimeter? If yes, you could measure the current going through the resistor and the voltage across the resistor. U/I = R.

Comment: I know that this is for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478242/resistor-without-terminals/478247?noredirect=1#comment1219243_478247 pick 4 contrasting resistors in the same order of magnitude of the sense resistor, eg  120, 330, 820, 2200 the then measure the voltage each gives

Comment: Hello again Jason. I could use the 5V output, would that be preferred, and why?

Comment: yes, because the diodes would then contribute a smaller fraction of the signal, you'd have almost 4V of signal instead of just over 2V

Comment: What is the purpose of the circuit? And silicon diodes typically have 0.7V drop.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage the analog pin of the Arduino will see is

$$ V_\text{analog pin} = \frac{ 3.3V-2 \cdot V_\text{diode drop} }{R_1+R_2} \cdot R2$$

The diode drop depends on the current throug the diodes, which depends on the value of R1.
When the current is in the milli-ampere range, you can assume a voltage drop of about 0.6V and 0.7V.

Comment: Your equation is not showing correctly, not for me anyway.

Comment: @Bart as in: the Mathjax is not parsed correctly or as in: the equation is incorrect?

Comment: @Bart:  Reload the page.  MathJax often has rendering problems after an edit.

Comment: @Huisman it is correct now. Previously i saw the raw Mathjax code.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate R1:

\$R_1 = R_2( \frac{ V_{IN} - 2V_F }{V_{OUT}} - 1)\$

Vout is the voltage you want at the Arduino pin

Vin is 3.3 in your diagram

Vf is the forward voltage of the diode, typically around 0.6 or 0.7V depending on
current.

So suppose Vf = 0.65V, Vin = 3.3V and Vout = 1.2V and R2 = 1K

R1 = 667\$\Omega\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBiBhW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you pick an approximate value for Vf you can calculate the resistors, then
refer to a datasheet or measure Vf (or use LTspice) and then refine the resistors by iteration, since Vf is not very sensitive to small changes in current.

If we simulate this we get 1.27V so Vf is more like 0.6V.

Recalculate and we get R1 = 750\$\Omega\$, which simulates as 1.21V, pretty close.

With higher values of R1+R2 the current will be less, so Vf will be lower.

If you were doing this for a post-secondary education problem set, you'd probably be expected to use the diode equation for Vf, which might have to be solved numerically.

Comment: @Sphero Pefhany thanks for your response Sphero. I was having trouble with your formula until I realised Vf for these diodes is 0.5. Is the voltage drop across the diodes independent of the resistor values? Thanks!

Comment: As I tried to explain above, the Vf will increase with lower resistor values (or more current because of the voltage difference). So if the voltages are closer together or the resistors are higher value for the same voltages, the value of Vf will be lower.. [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/iLRJ2FN.png) the typical graph. So 0.5V is about right for 100uA and 0.6V for about 1mA, roughly. I don't  know why you would put two resistors in there, though, and even one is not always required  if you just want to read 5V into a 3.3V input.

Comment: Oh thank you very much Spehro, much appreciated. The circuit shown is a simplification. I'll have an array of these (https://imgur.com/M0X9XFq) with different resistor values, so each one has a unique "signature" when making contact with two fixed terminals (https://imgur.com/ilVBGnf). Make sense? If so, do you see any issue with it?